Ejecutar herramientas de linea de comandos sin instalarlas, con docker
¿Cómo podemos usar Docker para ejecutar aplicaciones que no hemos instalado en la máquina host y que esas aplicaciones se comporten como si estuvieran instaladas?

Para ser más claro, voy a poner un ejemplo:
Supongamos que queremos usar aws-cli para listar nuestros buckets de S3 con el comando aws s3 ls. Para evitar instalar aws-cli, podemos usar docker con el siguiente comando:
docker run --rm  public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli s3 ls

Esto, desde luego, va a ejecutar el comando en cuestión, pero va a dar error porque aws-cli busca las credenciales de aws en el archivo .aws/credentials y este archivo no existe.
Para hacer que el comando se ejecute con éxito, se debe montar el directorio .aws/ de la máquina host como volumen del contenedor como sigue:
docker run --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws  public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli s3 ls

Lo que, en efecto, funciona si tenemos correctamente configuradas las credenciales en la máquina host.
Pero claro, es engorroso escribir todo este comando cada vez que queremos ejecutar un comando de aws cli, por lo que podemos crear un alias en nuestro archivo de configuración bash (.bashrc) para simplificar el comando:
alias aws='docker run --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws  public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli'

Y ahora nuestro comando sería:
aws s3 ls

A simple vista parece que este alias tiene el comportamiento que tendría aws-cli si estuviera instalado y ya esta pregunta estaría resuelta.
fin del ejemplo

Dada la naturaleza de Docker, sabemos que hay algunos casos en los que nuestro alias no se comporta como su versión instalada en especial con el manejo de archivos y permisos.
Mi implementación más cercana es crear una funcion bash y cargarla en el .bashrc/.bash_profile:
#! /bin/bash

function php {
  local container_name="php-${USER}"
  local workdir="/var/www/html"
  local docker_image="php:8.2-cli" 
  local local_dir=$(pwd)
  local entrypoint=php
  local ports="8000:8000"

  if docker ps -a --format '{{.Names}}' | grep -q $container_name; then
    docker exec -it $container_name $entrypoint $@
  else
    docker run -it --rm --name $container_name -u $(id -u):$(id -g) --publish $ports --entrypoint $entrypoint -v $local_dir:$workdir --workdir $workdir $docker_image $@
  fi
}
php $@


Como podrán ver, tiene un fallo y es que si un comando queda en espera y ejecuto en otra terminal (DESDE OTRA CARPETA) la misma herramienta (php en este caso), el comando va a reutilizar el contenedor del comando que está en espera y, por tanto, usar el sistema de archivos incorrectos.
Con esta pregunta busco completar la funcion de arriba o obtener un mejor enfoque si ya lo hay para realizar lo ya expuesto.
De momento voy a intentar esto:
con docker (y quiza con jq), al ejecutar un comando  voy inspeccionar los contenedores que están corriendo el comando en cuestion (en este caso php) , revisar si los volúmenes que tienen montados apuntan al path pwd y solo en ese caso reusar el contenedor, de lo contrario crear otro.

Se me ocurre que al contenedor le installes SSH y lo corras como si fuera una máquina virtual independiente, lo dejes corriendo con el servicio ssh, y entres en él cuando lo necesites y le instalas lo que necesites y todo se va a hacer únicamente con los recursos dentro.
Por ejemplo,

Primero creas un par de llaves: ssh-keygen -f ./docker-keys, y das enter para que no tenga passphrase. Ahí te va a crear dos archivos, uno "docker-keys", y otro "docker-keys.pub".
Creas un Dockerfile algo así (más lo que le quieras instalar) para que corra ssh:


FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    echo "<el contenido de tu archivo docker-keys.pub>" > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

con el contenido de tu archivo docker-keys.pub

Creas la imagen: sudo docker build -f <tu archivo Dockerfile> -t ssh_image .
Creas el contenedor mapeando el puerto local 2222, al puerto 22 de dentro del contenedor (al puerto donde esta expuesto el servicio que corre ssh): sudo docker run -d -p 2222:22 --name ssh_container ssh_image
Topa que en que IP local está corriendo ese contenedor:

$ sudo docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ssh_container
172.17.0.2


Corre ssh indicando el usuario, ip que encontraste, y señalando la llave privada con la que te vas a autenticar: ssh root@172.17.0.2 -i ./docker-keys "<cualquier comando>"

Una vez que sepas que puedas correr comandos dentro de tu contenedor, puedes hacer este experimento:

Entras a tu contenedor con sudo docker exec -it ssh_container /bin/bash
Creas un programa y le das permisos de ejecución: echo '#!/bin/bash echo Estas en $(pwd), como usuario $(whoami)' > /root/programa.sh && chmod u+x /root/programa.sh
Lo ejecutas FUERA del contenedor tan solo con ssh:

ssh root@172.17.0.2 -i ./docker-keys "/root/programa.sh"
Estas en /root, como usuario root

Esto significa que desde afuera del contenedor, puedes correr un programa dentro de un contenedor tan sólo indicando su dirección IP, puerto, y el programa o comando.
Para hacerlo todavía más resumido, podrías modificar tu archivo "~/.ssh/config" añadiendo una entrada:
Host mi_docker
    Hostname <la ip a la que el contenedor está mapeado>
    User <usuario al que le instalaste las llaves>
    IdentityFile <path COMPLETO de donde estan las claves privadas de ssh>

Guardas ese archivo, y ahora puedes ejecutar tan sólo:
ssh mi_docker "<cualquier comando>"

Y listo.
Y con un alias queda tanto más compacto, pero más anidado.
alias mi_comando='ssh mi_docker "<cualquier comando>"'
Y listo para el infierno de depurar esto cuando tengas problemas con el contenedor.
Update 1
Se me ocurrió que puedes montar ese contenedor a una carpeta, y acceder a esa carpeta (que en realidad es únicamente una interfaz al sistema de archivos del contenedor) como si fuera parte de tu computadora.
Lo que esté dentro de esa carpeta en realidad no está en tu computadora, sino en el contenedor de docker, pero la diferencia con el enfoque anterior es que lo que ejecutes no va a estar aislado de las variables, permisos, y scopes de tu computadora local.
Por ejemplo, primero -ya teniendo ese contenedor corriendo ssh como en el paso anterior- montamos ese contenedor via sshfs.

Instalamos sshfs: sudo apt install sshfs -y
Creamos una carpeta donde vamos a montar nuestro relajo: mkdir -p /mnt/docker_mount/
Usamos sshfs para montar un directorio remoto a un directorio local a través de sshfs: sshfs mi_docker:/root /mnt/docker-mount

Aquí hay que repetir varias cosas para aclaralas. "mi_docker" es el alias del hostname que editamos en el paso anterior en el archvo ~/.ssh/config, recordemos que es un alias de algo como "[usuario de ssh de docker]@[ip del contenedor]:/root", más la dirección de la clave privada con la que nos autenticamos con el contenedor.
4. A gozar. Dentro de nuestra carpeta local /mnt/docker-mount/ vamos a encontrar todos los programas que creamos DENTRO del contenedor, pero como si estuvieran en nuestro sistema de archivos. Si corremos el mismo programa que corrimos en el pasó anterior tendremos esto:
/mnt/docker-mount/programa.sh
Estas en /mnt/docker-mount/, como usuario cuau

En este caso, mi usuario en mi computadora local (no en el contenedor) es "cuau".
Si quieres desmontar este sistema de archivos remoto, salte de esa carpeta y ejecuta: fusermount -u /mnt/docker-mount, y ya no tendrás acceso a ese sistema de archivos remoto ni a los programas.
Si quieres algo aislado, te recomiendo el enfoque de puro ssh. Si quieres nomas un plug-in/plug-out que TOMA EN CUENTA los archivos y variables de tu host, intenta con el de sshfs.
